# Can i send savfig to python telegram bot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I tried to add bot.sendPhoto(chat_id=chat_id, photo='http://s33.postimg.org/plci93h4v/image.png'), where i have savfig and need to send the image to my telegram bot

```
import telebot
from flask import Flask, request


token = '9542...................ke8nT10'

URL = 'http://re......here.com/'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token, threaded=False)
bot.remove_webhook()
bot.set_webhook(url=URL)

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    update = telebot.types.Update.de_json(request.stream.read().decode('utf-8'))
    bot.process_new_updates([update])
    return 'ok',200

def code:
        plt.savefig('plot_name.png', dpi = 300)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])  # welcome message handler
def start(message):
    bot.sendPhoto(chat_id=chat_id)
```

I am trying to send the savfig in code: function to my telegram bot

Comment: Have you tried downloading the Photo in first instance? For e.g. with the help of urllib and then sending it via sendPhoto(chat_id = chat_id, photo = open('file.png', 'rb')) ?

Comment: Have the code in pythonanywhrre server , how can I download there

Answer (score 0):

bot.send_photo(chat_id, photo=open('plot_name.png', 'rb'))